# Keep keyboard visible on multiple view controllers and focused on every textfield

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

This is how my storyboard currently looks like: **onboardingVC** contains **UIView Container** that embeds **PageViewController** which holds a reference to the next 3 ViewControllers

[image]
In the 3 ViewControllers (Email, Password, Nickname) I have a textfield and in all 3 view controllers in ViewDidLoad() I call textField.becomeFirstResponder()

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

For now the keyboard just shows on EmailVC (first page in PageViewController).

But when I tap the Next button and go to the next two view controllers, the keyboard shows for a millisecond and dismisses immediately.

**So, my question is how to make the keyboard persist, showing and focused on all three textfields**

```
class OnBoardingViewController: UIViewController {

weak var delegate: NextPageDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func nextPage(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.showNextPage()
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == Const.Segue.embeded_email_registration {
        delegate = segue.destination as? PageViewController
    }
}

@IBAction func dismissVC(_ sender: UIButton) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

```
protocol NextPageDelegate: class {
func showNextPage()
```

}

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController {

fileprivate lazy var pages: [UIViewController] = {
    return [
        self.getViewController(withIdentifier: Const.EmailRegistration.EmailVC),
        self.getViewController(withIdentifier: Const.EmailRegistration.PasswordVC),
        self.getViewController(withIdentifier: Const.EmailRegistration.NicknameVC),
        self.getViewController(withIdentifier: Const.EmailRegistration.BirthdateVC)
    ]
}()

fileprivate func getViewController(withIdentifier identifier: String) -> UIViewController {
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate   = self

    if let firstVC = pages.first {
        setViewControllers([firstVC], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    removeSwipeGesture()
}

func removeSwipeGesture() {
    for view in self.view.subviews {
        if let subView = view as? UIScrollView {
            subView.isScrollEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

}

extension PageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                        viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let currentIndex = pages.index(of: viewController)!
    let previousIndex = currentIndex - 1
    return (previousIndex == -1) ? nil : pages[previousIndex]
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                        viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let currentIndex = pages.index(of: viewController)!
    let nextIndex = currentIndex + 1
    return (nextIndex == pages.count) ? nil : pages[nextIndex]
}
```

}

```
extension PageViewController: NextPageDelegate {
func showNextPage() {
    if let currentViewController = viewControllers?[0] {
        if let nextPage = dataSource?.pageViewController(self, viewControllerAfter: currentViewController) {
            setViewControllers([nextPage], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
class EmailInputViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

}

**EmailInputViewController, PasswordInputViewController and NicknameInputViewController have the same code**

Comment: As viewcontroller change that is the default behaviour of keyboard will dismissed and as the answer provided put becomeFirstResponder in viewwillappear that keyboard open. If you want that keep open you should try diffrent way like UIPageViewcontroller or horizontal scroll view with view's it look like paging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have prepared a demo, Please have a look

**PageviewController**

```
import UIKit

class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    var pages = [UIViewController]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let first = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "first") as! FirstViewController
        let second = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second") as! SecondViewController

        pages.append(first)
        pages.append(second)

        setViewControllers([first], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

        self.addChildViewController(first)
        self.addChildViewController(second)
        self.didMove(toParentViewController: first)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex: Int = pages.index(of: viewController)!
        let previousIndex = abs((currentIndex - 1) % pages.count)
        return pages[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex: Int = pages.index(of: viewController)!
        let nextIndex = abs((currentIndex + 1) % pages.count)
        return pages[nextIndex]
    }

    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return pages.count
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

}
```

**Container view controller which is holding PageViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var pageVC: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {

        if let page = self.childViewControllers.first as? PageViewController {
            let second = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second") as! SecondViewController

            page.setViewControllers([second], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

        }
    }
}
```

**And This is my FirstViewController which is the first page of PageViewController**

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var firstText: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        firstText.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

}
```

**SecondViewController**

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var secondText: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        secondText.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

> This is my storyboard: 
>   [image]
>
> In this demo keybord not down when user click on next button

Comment: thank you for replying, but again on the next view controller after the keyboard shows it immediately gets closed

Comment: Can you try this in "viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)"

Comment: in viewDidAppear the keyboard does not pop up at all, but becomeFirstResponder() gets called

Comment: Can you show me your code, actually I want to check that what you have done?

Comment: Please check, I have added a code! This is demo code and not in a managed way. So please check you concern only